# Javapoet and generic class declarations

Tags: java, generics, javapoet

How do I get javapoet to generate the java code below?

```
class B<T extends U> implements A<T> {

}
```

I know there is a `class WildcardTypeName`, but it can only generate? `extends U` or `? super U`.

what I want is `T extends U`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your description, `U` and `A` should be exist class. You can use following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  TypeVariableName t = TypeVariableName.get("T").withBounds(U.class);
  TypeSpec type = TypeSpec.classBuilder("B")
      .addTypeVariable(t)
      .addSuperinterface(ParameterizedTypeName.get(ClassName.get(A.class), t))
      .build();
  JavaFile.builder("", type).build().writeTo(System.out);
}
```

Its output is

```
import yourpackage.A;
import yourpackage.U;

class B<T extends U> implements A<T> {
}
```